# Can't decrypt a string having letters followed by their frequency

Tags: java, string

For a given string, which has character and the number of times the character appeared, decode to the full string. During encoding if the character appear only once, then no number will be next to that character.

Input: `"a5br3"`
Output: `"aaaaabrrr"`

Im getting output as :

```
aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaabrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrrr
```

Is my logic is correct? What is wrong with my code?

```
public String func (String str){
    if(str==null){
        return null;
    }
    String result="";
    for(int i=0;i<str.length();i++){
        char c= str.charAt(i);
        if(Character.isLetter(c)){
            result+=str.charAt(i);
        }
        else if(Character.isDigit(c)){
            for(int j=0;j<c;j++){
                result+=str.charAt(i-1);
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You confused the numerical value of a digit with it's character code. Moreover, since the character is already appended once to the string we need to add one less copy during the loop. You can use code like this:

```
for(int j=1;j<(c - '0');j++) ...
```

Comment: for tis input:Input: "a10br3a3"
Output: "aaaaaaaaaabrrraaa"

Comment: For this       Input: "a10br3a3"
Actual Output iis : "aaaaaaaaaabrrraaa"                                                              but im getting abrrraaa.......... it doesnt take 10 as a single digit ......

Comment: Sure not. If you can also have multi digit numbers you need to collect all digits and to convert them to a number. I just took what you initially had in the program.